# Compiler system software or application software

Tags: c++, operating-system, system

Is compiler system software or application software? I have checked  few sites they mentioned system software few Application software. Can you please give me conclusion for this?

Comment: It's application software. Why do you care?

Comment: I am going to write competitive exam. there is one question. So i need to care about that.

Comment: Why negative marks ? Many people have same doubt. Looks this is system software.

Comment: Not my downvote, but the question _is_ somewhat strange. But anyway what is the definition of "system software" anyway? IMO it's more or less a matter of interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

All compilers are *application software*.

Many times, compiler required many system libs for compile your software.

Answer (score -1):

COMPILER is a System software

System software is a type of computer program designed to run hardware and software programs on a computer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).